# Xcode 9 - Use a language depending on the target

Tags: xcode, localization

I have an application which is using English - Development Language and Danish. 
Because I don't know Danish it would be easy for me to have both languages available for a target that I am using for development and to keep only Danish for the target that I use for production/Danish testers.

It is possible to achieve this?
Thank you!